# Authentication: signed cookies vs. jwt token

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, jwt, passport.js

I'm making server-side authentication. I found 2 ways:

1. Create a cookie with `value` being `user id`, then sign it with `HMAC`
2. Create a JWT token which `payload` being `user id`, then sign it with `HMAC`

Both methods seem to work similarly. However, on the Internet, I found **JWT** is **more widely used** to authenticate user, but not many people talk about authenticate user using **signed cookies**...

But I'm tempted to use **signed cookies** because it's easier to implement. So I'm wondering **on the security-level** are the two methods the same?